# Using a free database for the Geoip logstash feature

Tags: logstash, geoip, freegeoip

I have enabled the geoip of logstash plugin, but I cannot manually insert the database I want into the config file and it keeps giving the following error.
I didn't understand this exactly, the geoip function just needs to be activated on the logstash. Do I have a mistake in the pipeline config file?What is the difference between `dat` and `your mmbr` extension in `your maxmind` databases?

pipeline:

```
filter {
   grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{IP:clientip} - %{DATA:user_name} \[%{HTTPDATE:access_time}\] \"%{WORD:http_method} %{DATA:url} HTTP/%{NUMBER:http_version}\" %{NUMBER:response_code} %{NUMBER:body_sent_bytes} \"%{DATA:referrer}\" \"%{GREEDYDATA:agent}" }
        }
   geoip {
       source => "[clientip]"
       ecs_compatibility => disabled
       target => "geoip"
       database => “/usr/share/logstash/database/GeoIPCity.dat”
    }
```

error log:
image attach
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTKQl.png)